# DateInterval returning 0 months?

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I want to calculate how many months there are between two dates:

```
$from = new DateTime('2014-11-01 00:00:00');
$to = new DateTime('2014-12-01 00:00:00');
$diff = $from->diff($to);
echo $diff->m; // <-- 0
```

The difference between `2014-11-01 00:00:00` and `2014-12-01 00:00:00` should be exactly one month, right? But `$diff->m` says **0**. `diff->d` says 30 days instead.

If I try the same with `2014-01-01 00:00:00` and `2014-02-01 00:00:00`, `$diff->m` says **1** month now, which is correct.

Did I miss something?

---

**EDIT:**

As I only need to calculate how many months there are between the two set dates and the user inserts the *from* and *to* dates with month and year (12/2014), the best solution working for me is simply increasing the *to* date:

```
// user inserts
// from: 11/2014
// to: 12/2014

$from = new DateTime('2014-11-01');
$to = new DateTime('2014-12-15');
$diff = $from->diff($to);

echo $diff->m // outputs 1
```

Thanks STLMikey for feeding me the answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

DateInterval works a bit...oddly in many scenarios.

Try `$diff->format('%m month, %d days');` and see if that helps clarify some things. `%m` and `%d` often return `0` if the difference is better covered by a different measure.

for example:

`$from = new \DateTime('2014-01-01 00:00:00');
$to = new \DateTime('2014-02-15 00:00:00');`

$diff->m of these two dates will also return "1", as per the documentation.

I personally tend to just use `$interval->format('%a total days');` as it doesn't confuse itself (or me) trying to be too smart.

Comment: `$diff->format('%m month, %d days');` returns _"0 month, 30 days"_ in the first example. The difference is 30 days in fact, but that should be displayed as 1 month, 0 days right?

Comment: $from = new \DateTime('2014-01-01 00:00:00');
$to = new \DateTime('2014-02-15 00:00:00');    the difference in months is also "1" in this case too ... months are not calculated as 30 days. %d just gives you the difference of month values

Answer (score -1):

On my computer the code produces different results. My php version is 5.3.13.

```
<?php

$from = new DateTime('2014-11-01 00:00:00');
$to = new DateTime('2014-12-01 00:00:00');
$diff = $from->diff($to);
echo $diff->m; // outputs 1
echo $diff->d; // outputs 0

?>
```

EDIT 1: another output

```
<?php

$from = new DateTime('2014-01-01 00:00:00');
$to = new DateTime('2014-02-01 00:00:00');
$diff = $from->diff($to);
echo $diff->m; // outputs 1
echo $diff->d; // outputs 0

?>
```

Comment: Just FYI: You can read this if you want: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174 And a short quote from there: `Can I put my comment in an answer?

No.`

Comment: Sorry, if I can help contribute to the person figuring out the problem wouldn't it be an injustice to not do it? Should I delete this?

Comment: No, i would just start your answer differently.

Comment: @IanThompson thanks for your contribution - it really helps me, as i can see that this looks like a bug in php. My server running PHP 5.4.6 echos `$diff->m;` to 0.